IME selection for the input or textarea tag with Blazor
I made up one Blazor project on API, WASM, Hybrid.
But when I wanted to collect the user data through 'Input, InputText, TextArea, etc',
it was mandatory to start with eng IME mode first, though I wanted it is started with Ko or Ja at the first place.
This is a big problem to me, because I have over 200 input fields to collect user data in those IME(ko, ja first).
I am wordering, even though Chrome had deprecated IME active support(style="ime-mode:active"), but when I surf other site from like php, it still is working well.
Is this only Blazor problem?
Is there no other way to deal with it?
So, I want the en or ja IME to be entered first in the text field in the Blazer project.
